# Removing Duplicate Node on Value Specific using XSLT

Tags: xslt

In the given xml, When ItemtypeCode value is 'S', then it should check for duplicate 'original-order-no' value, if found then remove the corresponding 'order' node, When ItemtypeCode value is 'R', it can allow duplicates.

Please suggest the XSLT for this scenario.
Thanks in Advance!

XML

```
<orders> 
<order order-no="5000003324123">
<original-order-no>5000003324892</original-order-no>
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="itemTypeCode">S</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</order>
<order order-no="5000003324456">
<original-order-no>5000003324892</original-order-no>
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="itemTypeCode">R</custom-attribute>     
</custom-attributes>
</order>
<order order-no="5000003324678">
<original-order-no>5000003324892</original-order-no>
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="itemTypeCode">S</custom-attribute>     
</custom-attributes>
</order>
<order order-no="5000003324910">
<original-order-no>5000003324892</original-order-no>
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="itemTypeCode">R</custom-attribute>     
</custom-attributes>
</order>
</orders>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
<orders> 
<order order-no="5000003324123">
<original-order-no>5000003324892</original-order-no>
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="itemTypeCode">S</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</order>
<order order-no="5000003324456">
<original-order-no>5000003324892</original-order-no>
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="itemTypeCode">R</custom-attribute>     
</custom-attributes>
</order>
<order order-no="5000003324910">
<original-order-no>5000003324892</original-order-no>
<custom-attributes>
  <custom-attribute attribute-id="itemTypeCode">R</custom-attribute>     
</custom-attributes>
</order>
</orders>`
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a grouping problem, see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml, in XSLT 2.0 you can solve it using

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:key name="dupes"
        match="order[custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id = 'itemTypeCode'] = 'S']"
        use="original-order-no"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="order[custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id = 'itemTypeCode'] = 'S'][not(. is key('dupes', original-order-no)[1])]"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

with XSLT 1.0 you need to change the last template to

```
    <xsl:template match="order[custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id = 'itemTypeCode'] = 'S'][not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('dupes', original-order-no)[1]))]"/>
```